# Dynamic column selection the EF4 way

Tags: sql, vb.net, entity-framework-4

I have a function that I'm trying to change from old SQL way to EF4. I know the old SQL way isn't great, but I couldn't think of a better way of doing it. Now I can't seem to figure out how to make it work in EF...

My function passes in 3 values `Pos, MethID` and `PriceBreak`. First basically I select a row then I need to select a column. but this column can change...

Original SQL:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT " & PriceBreak & _
    " AS SelectedBreak FROM PrintCost WHERE MethodID = " & MethID & _
    " AND Position =  " & Pos & " ;"
```

New EF way so far!

```
Using db As New quotingSystemDevEntities
    Dim PriceBrakeCost = (From Breaks In db.PrintCosts 
                         Where Breaks.MethodID = MethID And Breaks.Position = pos
                         Select Breaks.XXXX).SingleOrDefault
    Return PriceBrakeCost
End Using
```

I my old SQL stuff the XXXX bit changes, whats selected. How is this possible in EF? Or perhaps there is a better way to do this?

Hope this makes sense! Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can probably pass in a lambda function to select the specific field you want each time. I'm not sure how to do it in that LINQ syntax, though, and you're going to lose type safety obviously (unless you write specific cases for every type returned).

Comment: Will the selected column always be of the same data type?

Comment: Hi, yes the data type will always be the same.

Comment: In that case your function can accept an `Expression(Of Func(Of PrintCost, T))`, where `T` is the type of your selected column. You would pass in a lambda that returns the property you need.